# Random gen method in java doesn't seem random

Tags: java, random

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [True random generation in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/381037/true-random-generation-in-java)
>   [Java random always returns the same number when I set the seed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5533191/java-random-always-returns-the-same-number-when-i-set-the-seed)

I run this piece of code in one of my programs.

```
public String[] gen_phase_zero() {
        Random generator = new Random();
        int r = generator.nextInt(2);
        if (r == 1) {
            String big = "A";
            String small = "a";
            return new String[] { big, small };
        } else {
            String big = "B";
            String small = "b";
            return new String[] { big, small };
        }
    }
```

If I run this a few times my output is like this.

Aa
Aa
Aa
Aa
Bb
Aa
Aa
Aa
Bb

It's not alwasy in that order. But it's almost never anything close to 50/50

### Update:

I'm not expeccting fifty fifty, but it seems that if "Aa" is selected first, then it'll be next around 3 more times, but if Bb is selected first, it'll be selected the next three times as well.

Comment: Of course you cannot rely on a `Random` class to generate random numbers with `50-50` probability.

Comment: Refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/381037/true-random-generation-in-java

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8044570/1037210) question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well it doesn't look too bad to me. Let's create a more statistically significant test:

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        Random rng = new Random();
        int total = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
            total += rng.nextInt(2);
        }
        System.out.println("Total: " + total);
    }
}
```

Sample output from 5 runs:

```
Total: 501184
Total: 499740
Total: 500116
Total: 500374
Total: 500413
```

Doesn't look *hugely* biased to me...

I got the same results when calling `new Random()` inside the loop instead of just once, too - although it's not a good idea to do that.

Comment: What's the significance of `total += rng.nextInt(2);` I'm really asking about the "2" at the end there. Still consider myself fairly new to java. Thanks.

Comment: @EGHDK: Well it matches your original code - it's an exclusive upper bound. Read the documentation for `Random.nextInt`. Basically that call will either return 0 or 1. I'm adding up the results, so you'd expect it to be about half of the number of iterations.

Comment: Interesting. Alright, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Do that 10000 times and it will approach 50:50.

Then toss a coin 9 times - the result will probably be similar to what random.nextInt() gives you.

The key here is to statistically significant amount of data.

And btw, use `random.nextBoolean()`

Answer (score -1):

You need to add a seed to your random class.  Typically it's a timestamp. So try something like

```
Random generator = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis);
```

Comment: You have to be careful with that, as you might be seeding all your "random" generators with the same seed. @EGHDK's best bet would actually to be to create as few Random instances as possible.

Comment: This will not help - it is actually worse than the default constructor (which uses a timestamp **and** a static counter.)